# "Having shared, in its presence..." vs "having, in its presence, shared..."

Tags: writing-style, phrase-usage, parentheticals

> The ocean. I was glad to have finally seen it. And even more glad of
> having shared--**in its presence**--my most intimate thoughts with Clara.
>
> The ocean. I was glad to have finally seen it. And even more glad of
> having--**in its presence**--shared my most intimate thoughts with Clara.

Which one of the correct form? If both are, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Both sentences are correct - they both make sense. Which one you decide to use depends on how you want to convey emotion and how you want the sentence to flow.

Answer (score 1):

The **narrative flow /breaks/is suspended/** after "having shared" in the first case, and after "having" in the 2nd.

The first suspends me **in a better-known state** — I know what follows after the auxiliary "having," i.e. "shared."

The second suspends me **in /lesser known/more indeterminate/ stat**e — I do not know what follows after the auxiliary "having". As a result, there might more anxiety in the reader - more suspense, but less satisfaction in terms of "knowing." One needs to choose his/her narrative "poison" :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new rule of grammar developing in English: never put adverbs or adverbial phrases between the verb and its direct object. [See this web page](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/28/an-adverb-between-a-verb-and-its-direct-object/) and [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/cant-adjuncts-be-placed-between-verbs-and-their-direct-objects).  The first one breaks this rule. A century or two ago, English writers had no qualms about putting adverbs in this position. For example, if you search Google books for *"took gradually the"*, you will find that nearly all the hits are before 1920. It's much less common today.

So I would recommend the second one; I think it sounds better.

Comment: And [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gave+immediately+the%2C+immediately+gave+the&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgave%20immediately%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20gave%20the%3B%2Cc0) is an Ngram showing the decline in popularity of putting an adverb between a verb and its object.